# Why IIS properties are case sensitve in some places and non case-sensitive in some other?

Tags: powershell, iis

we are updating IIS property Enable protocols via Powershell.

The following cmdlet is being used.

```
Set-ItemProperty $ConfigSiteName -name EnabledProtocols -Value "net.tcp"
```

The property is modified as net.tcp in IIS 7.5 as expected but in IIS 8.5 the default value http is unchanged. There is no error message also thrown

After much analysis we hit nowhere. But when we changed the property name to "enabledProtocols" it worked. As powershell is case-insensitive ,it is very hard to think in this small thing.

Is there any better way in powershell to enable protocol? Is this case sensitivity problem is known issue in IIS?

Comment: How did the failure manifest itself? An error message, if so can you post it?

Comment: @Kev No error messages are thrown. Just the property is not set correctly

Comment: What do you mean by "not set correctly"? Is it empty, doesn't change, some other unwanted value?

Comment: @Kev It did not change. The default value of the field was http and it remains unchanged

Comment: You just gave a case when case is sensitive. What is the insensitive case you were referring to? IIS 7 and above uses an XML based configuration, where such attributes are all case sensitive and I could not recall a case where an attribute is case insensitive.